# looping with when in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Am making a simple  calculator  in Kotlin but cant figure out why this function always returns result to be Zero I think I have  an error in my switch statement but cant figure out where??

I have tried replacing the value in the else part and realised that this is the only part being executed and all the oter cases are not being executed

Also if I intialize result with a value say 0, this is the value that is always being returned as result .

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit  var myresult : TextView
lateinit  var val1 : EditText
lateinit var  btn : Button
lateinit var val2 : EditText
lateinit var operation : Spinner



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     myresult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtresult)
     val1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.valone)
     val2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.valtwo)
     var btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
     operation = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)




    var opType = operation.selectedItem.toString()

    fun calculate() : Int {

        var value1 = Integer.parseInt(val1.text.toString())
        var value2 = val2.text.toString().toInt()
        var result : Int

        when (opType){

            "+" ->{result = value1 + value2
                    return result
                 }
            "-" ->{result = value1 - value2
                return result
            }
            "*" -> {result = value1 * value2
                return result
            }
            "/" -> {result = value1 / value2
                return result
            } else -> result = 0

        }

        return result
    }




    btn.setOnClickListener{

        println(calculate().toString())
        myresult.text = calculate().toString()


    }


}
```

}

Comment: Your title is not matching with your description.

Comment: Move this code var `opType = operation.selectedItem.toString()` inside in your `calculate()` function so that you get the current sign.

Comment: year the title sounds a bit different but am happy the question is understood and I have found help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably returns zero as that is the default when an unknown opType is supplied & you are setting the opType during the onCreate() event when the value of the operatrion spinner has yet to be selected.

As an aside you should probably try to avoid using 'var' whenever possible to avoid thread-saftey issues & to simplify testing.  I would personally rewrite your calculate function as something like this so that it can be invoked from the button clicked event.

```
fun calculate(opType: String, value1: Int, value2: Int) : Int {
    return when (opType){
        "+" -> value1 + value2
        "-" -> value1 - value2
        "*" -> value1 * value2
        "/" -> value1 / value2
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

Comment: @AustineGwa if your problem has been solved you may want to accept an answer